# Run executable with admin privileges at runtime

Tags: c++, windows, uac, visual-studio-6, privilege-elevation

I'm creating a program which runs different executables with different privileges when needed.
I was using this for elevating privileges

```
#include <windows.h>
...
ShellExecute( NULL,"runas","c:\\another.exe","",NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

but it doesn't work (maybe because of CPP and Windows versions?) and UAC window doesn't 
appear.
Adding manifest will do the work, but in that case normal users (non-admins) will not be able to run the program.

So, how can I do it?

Comment: what version of your windows sdk are you referencing?

Comment: Visual C++ 6 running on Windows 7

Comment: @DanielA.White And how can I know the version of SDK? In "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows" I see folders named "v5.0", "v6.0A", "v7.0A".

Comment: You need to run the executable as root to elevate another process.

Comment: @JensMunk it's possible, but UAC window will appear

Comment: Yes, of course. I usually work with embedded system so a popup is a no go. And then again, 90% of my work is non-windows

Comment: So you want to have a process that starts elevated processes without requiring elevation itself or triggering UAC popup? That is kinda like asking someone to fill a cup but the cup must remain empty at all times.

Comment: Are you sure your invoking application is not running as admin already? If your application is already running as admin, UAC would not appear when you launch another application.

Comment: @deGoot Program itself will NOT be run as admin, but it must be able to run programs with admin privileges when needed (with UAC window)

Comment: @Jet, I understand that's the expected usage, but I wanted to confirm that the program isn't running as admin in your testing environment.  Can you tell if `another.exe` is running as admin in your tests even though UAC doesn't come up?

Comment: @deGoot `another.exe` didn't start at all

Comment: Is there an error code returned from the `ShellExecute` function? As per MSDN: "If the function fails, it returns an error value that indicates the cause of the failure."